# Conditional Join possible in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a select query that joins the tables based on a condition (in this case, based on a value in one of the columns). I would like to do something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TableA
       INNER JOIN TableB ON (TableA.Column1 = TableB.Column1 OR TableA.Column1 = 0) -- Does not work!
```

Comment: As far as i know, Conditional Joins are not possible but there are other ways of achieving similar results. Can you update your question to include what you are trying to achieve in your example?

Comment: What result do you expect of A INNER JOIN B ON A.Col=0 ??

Comment: Sample data with expected results would be great here. Table definitions would be even better, but maybe not necessary for a question like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should achieve what you need:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA A
WHERE A.Column1 = 0
   OR EXISTS(
            SELECT B.Column1
            FROM TableB B
            WHERE B.Column1 = A.Column1
            );
```

Comment: This doesn't select any columns from TableB.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not exactly sure what you are doing but it seems like you are looking for an outer join:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.Column1 = TableB.Column1
WHERE TableB.Column1 IS NOT NULL
   OR TableA.Column1 = 0
```

Comment: Same exact answer I just wrote, only faster. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want rows from Table A and rows from Table B, just use two select statements separated by a **UNION** command.